# How can I fix the XmlHttp error while sending messages to a user?

Tags: die2nite, technical-issues

I tried to send an object via message to a fellow user, but got this message instead:

> XmlHttp error: an unknown error occured, preventing the page to  load properly. Please disable any software that may interfer with  the download (antivirus, spyware protection, internet protection, ...).

How do I fix it?

Comment: You seem to get a similar error if you spend the AP to complete a construction. It seems entirely harmless in that context. They really need to tidy their AJAX.

Answer (score 2):

This is likely an erroneous error message.

The real problem is your recipient has no room in his chest to receive your object.